# Stubbing functions used by other functions within es6 modules

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, sinon

I've been thinking about how to test particular functions used by other functions within the same file.

For example, say I have two functions within one file:

```
// validators.js
export const required = ...;
export const containsUppercase = ...;
export const containsNumber = ...;

export const password = (val) => [required, containsUppercase, containsNumber].every(f => f(val));
```

So clearly, the password validator depends on the `required`, `containsUppercase` and `containsNumber` functions. But what if I wanted to stub those out, so my tests didn't actually have to care about those functions or how they validate.

This is a simple, silly example, but I've ran into the same problem with more complex scenarios.

For example, if I try to do this with sinon, I might try doing this:

```
import * as validators from './validators';

sinon.stub(validators, 'required').returns(false);
sinon.stub(validators, 'containsUppercase').returns(true);
sinon.stub(validators, 'containsNumber').returns(true);

// test
expect(validators.password('notImportant')).toBe(false);
```

I tried doing this, but I couldn't get it to work. I found that I could get it to work, if I did something like this, though I haven't tested it.

```
const required = ...;
const containsUppercase = ...;
const containsNumber = ...;

const password = (val) => [ex.required, ex.containsUppercase, ex.containsNumber].every(f => f(val));

export default ex = {
  required,
  containsUppercase,
  containsNumber,
  password,
}
```

This solution is also ugly, since I now I'd have to worry about exporting the function in the right place, and also reference it through the export object.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Or rather, what would be the best way to test these kinds of functions?

Comment: Check out [`rewire`](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire). **EDIT**: never mind, `rewire` has issues with `const`.

Comment: Oh, that's disappointing. I been looking at babel-plugin-rewire, since rewire by itself doesn't appear to work for es6, judging from the docs. But if it doesn't support `const`, that's no good then.

Comment: You could try and see if `babel-plugin-rewire` works, though.

Comment: Testability is a very good reason to use IoC/DI, for example [this library](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) (heavily inspired by Angular 2 DI).

Comment: That is really cool, but unfortunately, I don't use typescript. Also, I'm very familiar with dependency injection, but having to call `password(requiredFn, uppercaseFn, numberFn, val)` every time doesn't seem very appealing to me. I did also think about changing the function to allow partial application: `const password = (required, uppercase, number) => val => ...`, but that would add a lot of complexity for such a simple example, so it doesn't seem viable.

Comment: Yes, calling it like that doesn't look good. That's why IoC container is welcome here, it handles dependencies for you. InversifyJS relies on decorators, it appears that you use Babel, it has the same decorator functionality as TS.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern in the second snippet is correct. `password` should refer to object methods in order for them to be mocked outside of `validators.js` scope.

The way to achieve this behaviour naturally in JS is using `this`:

```
export class Validators {
  required = (...) => { ... }
  ...
  password = (val) => [this.required, ...].every(...);
}

export default new Validators;
```

Or, with normal (non-arrow) functions:

```
export default {
  required(...) {
    ...
  }
  ...
  password(val) {
    [this.required, ...].every(...);
  }
}
```

In the second case `required`, etc. methods should be additionally bound if they use `this` when being called like `[this.required, ...].every(...)`.

Comment: This seems like an potentially viable approach. I'd still have to prepend everything with `this.`, but its better than what I had found. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, `this` is a constant price for some OOP goodness. Some Node/CommonJS packages refer to `exports` properties for the same purpose you've used `ex`, but this pattern isn't good enough ES6 modules, as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

*"but having to call password(requiredFn, uppercaseFn, numberFn, val) every time doesn't seem very appealing to me."*

You can use default values for parameters:

```
const defaultValidators = [required, containsUppercase, containsNumber];
const password = (value, validators = defaultValidators) => validators.every(f => f(value));
```

That allows you to call both `password('pass')` and `password('pass', [v => false])` and thereby stub your validation functions.

Comment: Default parameters totally slipped my mind. Thanks for reminding me! Still, having those extra parameters, that will only ever be used by tests seems pointless. I would still probably prefer my solution with partial application. Dependency injection is nice within sanity. This borders that sanity.